# Converting time, after 60 seconds it is only displaying the minutes. I am trying to display minutes followed by seconds.

Tags: android

How do I display the seconds followed by the minutes like 1:20.  Before the 60 seconds it displays the seconds but after the 60 seconds, it displays 1 mins. Following a tutorial but it is not what I am looking for.  If you need more information let me know.

```
public static final String MINUTES_FORMAT = "%d mins";
public static final String SECONDS_FORMAT = "%d secs";


private String parseDuration(int durationInSeconds) {
    return durationInSeconds > 60 ? String.format(MINUTES_FORMAT,
            durationInSeconds / 60) : String.format(SECONDS_FORMAT,
            durationInSeconds);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this

```
private String parseDuration(int durationInSeconds) {
    return String.format("%02dm :: ", durationInSeconds/60) + String.format("%02ds", durationInSeconds%60);
}
```

*haven't tested though*

Comment: Worked.  Thank you.  I'll accept your answer when it lets me.